# U-boot unreadable in LPC1788 uart

Tags: u-boot

I have an LPC1788 board with 128Mbyte NAND flash, 32Mbyte SDRAM and other peripherals.
I followed the instructions on http://www.lpcware.com/content/project/lpc177x8x-u-boot-port/u-boot-build-procedure
but the result the usart is unreadable when the u-boot is relocated the RAM.
I download the nxp compiled u-boot-lpc.hex too, and the result is same:

```
U-Boot 2011.06 (Aug 16 2011 - 16:47:50) 

NXP LPC1788 Cortex-M3 
DRAM: 32 MiB 
Flash: e1z K!A 
NAND: y2x#Mi 
#foeid !f pide 65472+ vedsigz 0@&1 
#fojd !f pide 65408+ vedsigz 0@&1 
pro!whoe "sadiyg fd "hocK!tae 
naf_rued_Zbt:8@adnaf_rued_Zbt:8@ad``lokk ad40x000000120000ztae 
naf_rued_Zbt:8@ad``lokk ad40x000000140x00ztae 
naf_rued_Zbt:8@adnaf_rued_Zbt:8@ad``lokk ad40x000000180000 
tae 
naf_rued_Zbt:8@ad``lokk ad40x0000001a0000ztae 
naf_rued_Zbt:8@adnaf_rued_Zbt:8@ad``lokk ad40x0000001e0000ztae 
sd rom(kffpt 40000 fa9xed***0Wa 
{viznm-|tdenv() failedL!usYxg `fa}{t 

In: serial 
Out: serial 
Err: serial 
uboot>
```

I send a 'help' command:

```
uboot> he`                                                                      
Uncmow0coMkan0'he`'x9 trl 'uboot>                                               
uboot>
```

I wrote a memtest before relocate and the memories works fine.
I have no idea whats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a custom board? 
Check the baudrate you are using on the terminal application. Make sure it is the same as the one programmed for the controller. Make sure the programmed settings in the controller are correct (this depends on the clocks of your HW). Until you verify your baudrates you can't check anything else. 
Also ask support from NXP, it is their patch. The patch seems to have never been mainlined, So they are the sole entity responsible for the patch.